# creating optiondialog on button click in titanium appcelerator

Tags: android, titanium

i am creating option dialog which contains radio buttons on right .this i saw in kitchensink i tried to create my own in other project but it showing error like applybutton(); undefined on button click ,i know that applybutton(); is function we have to define it but in kitchensink it directly shows how is that.
if i have to define function how could i go further,should i use images? please help me i am new to titanium appcelerator

```
 Ti.UI.setBackgroundColor('white');
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
 title: 'Click window to test',
backgroundColor: 'white',
exitOnClose: true,
fullscreen: false
});
var opts = {
cancel: 2,
options: ['Confirm', 'Help', 'Cancel'],
selectedIndex: 2,
destructive: 0,
title: 'Delete File?'
};
var dialog = Titanium.UI.createOptionDialog(opts);
dialog.addEventListener('click',function(e)
{
label.text = 'You selected ' + e.index;
if (e.button) {
            label.text += ' button';
        }  else {
            label.text += ' option';
        }});
var button1 = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title:'Show Dialog 1',
    height:40,
    width:200,
    top:10
});
button1.addEventListener('click', function()
{
    dialog.androidView = null;
        applyButtons();
    dialog.show();
});
win.add(button1);
win.open();
```

Comment: in android dialog box automatically has radio button, so once try removing `applyButtons();` method and check the working.

Comment: can you please elaborate what exactly you want your code to do?

Comment: @turtle thankyou its working after removing applyButtons();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the function applyButtons() was originally defined in the KitchenSink example code, be it at the top of the file or imported in via a commonjs module with a require statement.

If you want to call and use this method, place it at the top as a function expression eg.

```
var applyButtons = function() { 
     // Do something
};
```

You are getting a undefined error on the click eventLister as it can't find reference to this function.

Either remove / delete the call to the function or add it at the top of the code with whatever you want applyButtons to do.